# Convert pitch, roll, and yaw angles

Tags: math, orientation, android-sensors, compass, projective-geometry

I have a pitch, roll, and yaw angles (in degrees). I want to find the angle to north.
 My goal is to transform this info (pitch+roll+yaw) to a simple compass degrees.

Comment: You need to describe your scenario more precisely (especially in which order the rotations are applied). Isn't the angle to north just the yaw angle (maybe shifted a bit)?

Comment: Yes , you are right when the android phone is horizontal,the angle to north is just the yaw angle,but the mobile is not horizontal so to calculate the angle to north we have to use the pitch too.the problem is i don't know how to use the pitch and yaw to calculate the angle to north.

Comment: Please clarify which angle you want (between which directions).

Comment: I want the compass angle: between the direccional vector of the phone and and the north.

Comment: So if your phone is upright, you want 90°?